# Why this byte is not changing?

Tags: c#, memory

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Memory;

namespace xFUT22
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Mem m = new Mem();
        private void form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int pID = m.GetProcIdFromName("FIFA22"); //Gaseste ID-ul jocului
                bool openProc = false; //verifica daca procesul e gasit
                if (pID > 0) openProc = m.OpenProcess(pID); //Porneste procesul, daca exista

                if (openProc) // De aici incepe modificarea memoriei
                {
                    if (TF.Checked)

                        m.WriteMemory("0x143DD9FF9", "byte", "0x45");
                    else

                        m.WriteMemory("0x143DD9FF9", "byte", "0x41");


                }




            }
        }
    }
}
```

I opened the game, I started my app, I checked the box named "TF" and the bytes doesn't modify.

Why? That memory adress is on read/execute only but with programs like CHEATENGINE I can edit the bytes, but with my program, I can't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what is `Mem` here? that doesn't seem like a standard framework type, and passing addresses, values etc as strings seems very unusual; this seems like a question for the authors of `Mem`

Comment: as a side note: *constantly* checking and reapplying in a hot loop seems... odd; and I'm surprised that `TF.Checked` works - that looks like it would be a cross-threaded operation, which: isn't allowed; are you sure the worker hasn't exited with failure?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm sorry, I forgot to say I use memory64.dll nuget packages, which add some options that allow me more easily to edit memory.

And nope, I compiled it, no errors.

Comment: compiling doesn't mean it runs correctly; that would be a *runtime* error, not a compile-time one

Comment: @MarcGravell I am sorry I wasted your time, it didn;t worked because the program was made for x32 and the game is x64. Now I solved it, thanks